# Is it possible to change a whole row with 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-update

Hello everyone is it possible in sql to change a whole row with 1 value?
I have a whole row with email adresses but to do a test i need to change the email adresses to 1 email adress for example test@mail.com

i tried something like this

```
UPDATE dbo.employee
SET email = "test@mail.com"
```

can someone help plz?

Comment: you mean, entire column?

Comment: Add a WHERE clause to specify which rows to update.

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. odd object names like `"This is a strange column name"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'someone@somewhere.com'`.

Comment: It would help if you described your existing table structure with some sample data, and what are you expecting

Comment: @Ahmad its like a table with employee information and what i want is to change all email adresses of the employees to test@mail.com there are like 200 employees

Comment: If you really want to update all records in that table by setting them to that e-mail, then an update without WHERE clause will do just that. But you should use single-quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update entire table email id then use

```
UPDATE dbo.employee SET email = 'test@mail.com'
```

Or if you want any specific row to update then use

```
UPDATE dbo.employee SET email = 'test@mail.com' where id=2
```